# autoincrement in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I use this for autoincreamenting one column ,

`"create table info (ID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, age int)"`
for inserting in table I have this!

```
public static void databaseInsertInfoTable(int ID,int age){...}
```

when I want to call databaseInsertInfoTable it does not accept null for ID.

```
databaseInsertInfoTable(null,12);// this has error!
```

what value should I insert for ID??

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you'd use a ID with auto increment? [SQLite already has a field called `ROWID` (or `OID`)](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) than you can use for unique identifiers.

Comment: No I just need 1,2,3.... but thanks I will see how it works too:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1), using "null" for your insert should work just fine.

However, if you are using Java, you can't pass `null` where the parameter type is a primitive like `int`. You have to use one of Java's "[wrapper classes](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/java/miscellaneous_java/Java_Primitive_Types.html)" to be able to pass a null value, so try putting `Integer` there instead of `int`.

Comment: yes exactly I am using java. I saw your link you mean I should use this?                                        databaseInsertInfoTable((Integer) null,12); ?

Comment: Close. When you define your `databaseInsertInfoTable` method, it should look like this: `public static void databaseInsertInfoTable(Integer id, int age)`. This will allow you to pass null for `id`, but will not let you pass null for `age`

Answer (score 3):

You can also make the query without inserting the id parameter. It would be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Aigua (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,mq DOUBLE, total DOUBLE,emq DOUBLE,data DATETIME)
```

And then when you insert:

```
INSERT INTO Aigua (mq,total,emq,data) VALUES (aigua.getTotalm3(),aigua.getTotale(),aigua.getEm3(),formatedDate)
```

Notice that you don't need to modify the `id` field and the autoincrement still occurs.